# Infinite loop dispatching action in middleware

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to create a refresh login middleware (get a new jwt token when is about to expire). However, when I try to logout my user in case the token is already expired, the application freezes and I get a maximum callstack error (infinite loop). I'm currently using Redux Toolkit with configureStore and createSlice. In console log it prints a lot of DISPATCHING but if I console log anything in my action inside the createSlice, it doesn't print anything. So... I believe the problem is with the dispatch action

```js
// auto-login.middleware.js

const autoLogin =
  ({ getState, dispatch }) =>
  (next) =>
  (action) => {
    const { user } = getState()

    if (user) {
      const expDatetime = moment(user.exp * 1000)
      const tokenExpired = expDatetime < moment()

      if (!tokenExpired && moment() >= expDatetime.subtract(15, 'm')) {
        console.log('NOT EXPIRED')
        const { data } = apolloClient.mutate({ mutation: RENEW_TOKEN })
        dispatch(setUser(data.RenewToken))
      } else {
        // I saw this in a different post and tried, but still no resolutions:
        // return dispatch(setUser(null)).then(() => next(action))
        console.log('DISPATCHING')
        dispatch(setUser(null))
        console.log('DISPATCH COMPLETE')
      }
    }

    return next(action)
  }

export default autoLogin
```

```js
// user.slice.js

import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: null,
  reducers: {
    setUser: (_, action) => {
      console.log('ENTERED?')
      return action.payload
    },
  },
})

const { actions, reducer } = userSlice

export const { setUser } = actions
export default reducer
```

```js
// store.js

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(
  persistConfig,
  combineReducers({
    user: userReducer,
    categories: categoriesReducer,
    cart: cartReducer,
  })
)

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }).concat(autoLogin, logger),
})

export const persistor = persistStore(store)
```

Error from console log (if I put immutableCheck to false in configureStore, i still get an error but I get from moment.js which doesnt make sense to me):

```
immutableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:126 Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at detectMutations (immutableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:126:1)
at detectMutations (immutableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:161:1)
at detectMutations (immutableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:161:1)
at detectMutations (immutableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:161:1)
at detectMutations (immutableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:161:1)
at detectMutations (immutableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:161:1)
at Object.detectMutations (immutableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:86:1)
at immutableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:246:1
at Object.measureTime (utils.ts:9:1)
at immutableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:243:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After questioning and searching, I understood that Redux Middlewares executes before any Action occurs, which is why I was having a recursive problem - my middleware was re-executing each time dispatch was called. After checking if the action type is the same as the dispatch that I made inside the middleware, the recursion stopped since my dispatch is being fired only when a different action is called.

```js
// auto-login.middleware.js

const autoLogin =
  ({ getState, dispatch }) =>
  (next) =>
  (action) => {
    const { user } = getState()

    // solved with [ action.type !== 'user/setUser' ]
    if (user && action.type !== 'user/setUser') {
      const expDatetime = moment(user.exp * 1000)
      const tokenExpired = expDatetime < moment()

      if (!tokenExpired && moment() >= expDatetime.subtract(15, 'm')) {
        const { data } = apolloClient.mutate({ mutation: RENEW_TOKEN })
        dispatch(setUser(data.RenewToken))
      } else {
        dispatch(setUser(null))
      }
    }

    return next(action)
  }

export default autoLogin
```